# Is it common for Japanese school kids to live alone IRL?

Tags: japan

In so many animes, I have noticed that middle- and high-school kids live by themselves without any adults around to supervise. While this may serve as a useful plot device, I noticed that it happens far too often. Arima Kousei of *Your Lie in April* lives alone because his father is always out on business trips, Sakuta Azusagawa (*Rascal Does Not Dream of Bunny Girl Senpai*) and Kyon (*Haruhi Suzumiya* series) live with their younger sisters. Other characters of *Haruhi Suzumiya* like Yuki Nagato and Ryoko Asakura, both functionally human to that society, also live by themselves. **Is that common in Japanese society?**

[Having lived in multiple cities across multiple countries, I have never seen school kids living alone in houses like that. The best I've seen within the budget of older university students are single-room apartments or shared houses.]

Ideally, I'm looking for answers from people who have first-hand experience of school life in Japan. Answers based on studies and reports would be OK too, if you can translate the relevant information to English.

Comment: High school I guess, but middle really? Example please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't call it common, based on the data I've found, but the situation commonly portrayed in anime, manga and light novels *are not unheard of in real life*.

According to [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6177267/), those aged 15-19 that live alone **comprises only about 5% of the population**. It's worth nothing that the graph peaks at the age ranges of 20-24 and 80-84. **So while there are indeed students living alone in real life, it's not as common as anime, manga or light novels make it to be.**

There are also some discussion about this on different sites, some who've had Japanese friends who live alone. Here are some links if you'd like to read about their experiences. [Link 1](https://jref.com/threads/young-people-living-alone-in-japan.37107/), [Link 2](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/answerman/2017-01-16/.111067), [Link 3](https://www.reddit.com/r/japan/comments/2i79j5/are_underaged_students_living_alone_really_a_thing/)